# How to pass an array in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am communicating with a web server using my Qt application. I'am getting the response which contains a list of strings. So i'am storing the response into a QStringList. I have to display those string values in another form. How can i pass this list to another form.

Comment: Well, what widget are you displaying the data with?

Comment: I need to display it on lable. @Blender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `QStringList` (effectively `QList<QString>`) is part of Qt's [generic containers](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/containers.html) family, it uses [implicit sharing](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/implicit-sharing.html). This means that if you **pass-by-value**, you'll only perform a **shallow copy**, which is to say that you'll effectively only be passing the thin book-keeping part of the data structure - a pointer to a larger block of data which exists elsewhere. This block of data only needs to exist in one place (on the heap) but can be referenced by multiple `QLists`.

Do something like:

```
void Foo::Pass()
{
  QStringList List;
  //fill list
  mCatch->Catch(List);
}

void Bar::Catch(QStringList List)
{
  //use list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, you wish to join a list of string values into a single string and display it on a label? If so, use the [QStringList::join()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qstringlist.html#join)  method.

Comment: I think you have mistaken my question. I am doing the NFC project. When i detect the NFC tag i will send the tag details to server. From the server side i am getting response like "tagId&tagdata". I have extracted those response in to 2 elements tagId and tagdata and storing it in to the QStringList. This all the things done on tagdetails class and i used tagdetails form. Now my requirement is to pass the QStringList elements to the another class verify and form verify. I think my question is clear. please help me if you know. @Alexander Larin

Comment: void tagdetails::parseResponse(QString response)
{

    QStringList item = response.split('&');

    QString tagId = item[0];
    item.removeAt(0);
    QString buildingId = item[0];
    item.removeAt(0);
    qDebug()<<buildingId<<item<<tagId;

} now what ever in QStringlist i need to pass it to another calss .

Comment: I see it should work fine!
Could you write a code-snippet using pseudo-code or another way to explain that you want to do? How do you want to work with `buildingId` and `tagId` variables? Maybe you want that these variables will be integer type such as int type? If so, you should use something like that
`int buildId = item[0].toInt();`